# jQuery msgBox on Enter keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, msgbox

I have a jQuery msgBox to take usrID & PassWD With a button "Login". I want to associate button click function with "Enter" keypress. When one presses Enter it should work same as onclick on login button.

```
$.msgBox({
     type: "prompt",
     title: "Please Enter Your User Name & Password",
     inputs: [
          {header: "User Name*", type: "text", name: "userName", value: spl[0]},
          {header: "Password*", type: "password", name: "password"}
     ],
     buttons: [{value: "Login", type: "submit"}],
     success: function(result, values) {
           alert("Thanks...");
     }
});
```

Comment: I think the Keyboard Enter should work already if you use option `ok:'Login'` instead of adding a separate button `buttons: [{value: "Login", type: "submit"}]`. I take a look at code and button with class `'msgbox-ok'` seems to be already configured to trigger an OK in the plugin. HTH!

Comment: Tried that. but didn't work. on doing that it adding one more button named 'Cancel'. don't know where it is coming from. -@amitthk

Comment: Is the Keyboard enter working correctly in that case ( using `ok:'Login'`)? Then the issue would be to hide the 'Cancel' button.  That could probably be done considering the fact that its class is 'msgbox-no' (using CSS/Jquery selection) and it has dependency on options.confirm as well.

Comment: No. the keyboard enter also not working. -@amitthk

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13 && $("input[name='password']").val() != ""){
        $("input[name='Concluir']").click();
    }
});
```

I solved this problem using this code.

Comment: Please write your explanations in English.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && $("input[name='password']").val() != "") {
        $("input[name='Login']").click();
    }
});
```